# Почему кнопка назад в ToolBar не работает?

Tags: android

Почему кнопка назад в ToolBar не работает?

В ActionBar при нажатии она делала тоже самое что и кнопка назад на телефоне.

А тут нажимаешь и ничего не происходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              onBackPressed();
        }
});
```